# Json deserialize says children could not evaluate- xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have xamarin.forms app in which I am trying to consume an API. I can get the results but cant deserialize the data. It says "*Childern could not be evaluated*"

**My Json data**

```
{
        "success": true,
        "user": {
            "auth_uuid": "52320",      
            "current_store": 9,
            "permissions": {
                "write_notifications": true,           
            },
            "has_accepted_mobile_one_terms": false,
            "store": {
                "id": 9,
                "name": "South Street",
                "number": "0009",          
            }
        },
        "message": "User Logged In",
        "sidebarItems": [
            {
                "id": 53,
                "name": "Notification Center",

            }
        ],
        "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9"
 }
```

**My Corresponding C# class**

```
public clas loginData
{

public class Permissions
{
    public bool write_notifications { get; set; }
}

public class Store
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string number { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public string auth_uuid { get; set; }
    public int current_store { get; set; }
    public Permissions permissions { get; set; }
    public bool has_accepted_mobile_one_terms { get; set; }
    public Store store { get; set; }
}

public class SidebarItem
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public bool success { get; set; }
    public User user { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public List<SidebarItem> sidebarItems { get; set; }
    public string token { get; set; }
}
}
```

**My common class for making API call**

```
   public class APICall
        {
            Uri baseAddress = new Uri(CommonValues.BaseURL);
            string apiurl;
            string postdata;  
            public ErrorMessageData errorMessage;

            public APICall(string apiurl, string postdata)
            {
                this.apiurl = apiurl;
                this.postdata = postdata;
                this.loadingIndicator = loadingIndicator;
                errorMessage = null;
            }
            public T APICallResult<T>()
            {
                try
                {             
                    var client = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = baseAddress };
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                    var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, apiurl);
                    req.Content = new StringContent(postdata, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                    string stringObtained = "";
                    Task<string> task = Task.Run(async () => await Threading(client, req));
                    task.Wait();
                    stringObtained = task.Result;
                    var jsonObtained = Regex.Unescape(stringObtained);         
                    var resultJSON = '[' + jsonObtained + ']';
                    T resultObject;//Generic type object
                    try
                    {
                        resultObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(resultJSON);        
                        return resultObject;
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        List<ErrorMessageData> errorMessages = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ErrorMessageData>>(resultJSON);
                        errorMessage = errorMessages[0];

                        return default(T);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    errorMessage = new ErrorMessageData();
                    errorMessage.Flag = false;
                    errorMessage.Message = e.Message;

                    return default(T);
                }
            }
            async Task<string> Threading(HttpClient client, HttpRequestMessage req)
            {
                var resp = await client.SendAsync(req);
                resp.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                string stringObtained = await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                return stringObtained;
            }

        }
```

**How I am making API call**

```
 ObservableCollection<loginData> AuthDataObj;


                        string postdataForAuth = "{\"email\":\"" + "sample@sam.com" + "\",\"password\":\"" + "1234" + "\"}";
                        NCAPICall callForAuth = new APICall("/auth/login", postdataForAuth, null);
                        try
                        {
                            AuthDataObj = callForAuth.APICallResult<ObservableCollection<loginData>>();

                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            await DisplayAlert("Error", ex.Message, "ok");
                        }
```

How to solve this issue? Is this something related to  mapping of data to my model class?Any help is appriciated.

Comment: Does your api return List<yourJsonData> as `[]`. Can you check post the raw json returned from api as a sample

Comment: @HariHaran Defaultly the API does not return as []. SO added like this  var resultJSON = '[' + jsonObtained + ']';

Comment: It won't work then

Comment: I believe you should use `RootObject` instead of `loginData` something like `var AuthDataObj = callForAuth.APICallResult<ObservableCollection<RootObject>>();`

Comment: @pinedax  Please post it as answer. I will accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `RootObject` for the deserialization.

Change this line of code

`var AuthDataObj = callForAuth.APICallResult<ObservableCollection<RootObject>>();`